# Typo in CFT primary field transformation?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

[image]

Is this a typo? Shouldn't the first formula be

$$ \phi'(z', \bar{z}') = \lambda^h \bar{\lambda}^\bar{h} \phi(z, \bar{z}) $$  ?

For example, with $$ \lambda = 2 $$ the pair of points $(1,1)$ gets mapped to $(2,2)$; 
thus $\phi'(2,2)$ must be related to $\phi(1,1)$, not $\phi(4,4)$

Comment: Which textbook? Which page?

Comment: http://home.thep.lu.se/~alexey/FYTN10_files/exercise/Conformal_Th.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an unfortunate choice of $z, z'$, nevertheless it is correct.

Let $g\colon z \mapsto z'$ be a conformal transformation: a field $\phi$ is said to be primary of dimension $h$ if, under such transformation, it transforms as
$$
\phi'(z') = \left(\frac{\partial g(z)}{\partial z}\right)^{-h}\,\phi(z)
$$
where we look at just one coordinate at a time without loss of generality.

Let us now have the unfortunate choice of renaming $z\to z'$; the above thus becomes
$$
\phi'(z) = \left(\frac{\partial g^{-1}(z')}{\partial z'}\right)^{-h}\,\phi(z').
$$
Taking into account that 
$$
\left(g^{-1}\right)'(z) = \frac{1}{g'(g^{-1}(z))}
$$
or, equivalently, substituting directly $z'=g(z) =\lambda z$ (hence $z = g^{-1}(z') = \lambda^{-1}z'$) does the job.